# Writing animation using ffmpeg fails only with large dataset

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am trying to save an animation as an `mp4` using matplotlib's `animation` package. It goes well if the dataset isn't too large, but if I increase the  number of plots/frames in the animation then it fails with an error as if `fmpeg` wasn't installed:

```
/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py:784: UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
  warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 787, in save
    writer = writers[writers.list()[0]](fps, codec, bitrate,
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no idea what's causing this, since I have `fmpeg` and it works with less frames. I don't get why it should depend on the size of what you're trying to create.

I'm using python 3.4, matplotlib version 1.5.3 and ffmpeg version `N-81772-g99b823f`.

Comment: This error basically tells you that the ffmpeg writer is currently not available. This can have several reasons. Are you using this in a notebook or IPython console?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm using  IPython

Comment: I think the reason I wanted to know this is that it could happen that there is still an animation from a previous output active when trying to save the next,  which would make the ffmpeg unavailable until it finishes. So just to test that you might try to run the code in a completely fresh IPython console.